# Create an Event with a specific iCalUid

Tags: json, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to create an event in Office calendar ( with the Graph API ) setting the `iCalUId`?

I have tested with the Graph Explorer tool (from the web site) inserting this event (`POST /v1.0/me/events`):

```
{
    "subject": "My event",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2018-02-19T10:39:01.355Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2018-02-26T10:39:01.355Z",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "iCalUid": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F44A7CFB6DA9D301000000000000000100000004A4B349D0E9F1744BBA2F67E4D522179"
}
```

The system creates my event correctly, but it changes the UID with another ( auto-created, I suppose).

This is a part of the JSON response:

```
{
    "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000005BBB3A076EA9D301000000000000000010000000389E2C56CB68B74E807FE83A5CC60AAB",
    "subject": "My event",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2018-02-19T10:39:01.3550000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2018-02-26T10:39:01.3550000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

From the documentation only the `ID` field is read-only, so I am wondering if there is a way to set the `iCalUId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iCalUid` is a read-only calculated value so it cannot be manually set. You can see the details on how it is calculated in the [PidLidGlobalObjectId Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocal/1d3aac05-a7b9-45cc-a213-47f0a0a2c5c1).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an undocumented way (as far as I can tell, anyway) to modify the iCalUId. I've only tested with creation and not with updating, but I think it should work. Note that I don't know what other side-effects this will have, but for my use-case, it has worked so far.

The iCalUId gets its value from the [PidLidGlobalObjectId property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/dff9f123-fb9b-4581-a853-e70dd0cda6a7). You can modify this value using [SingleValueExtendedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0). For instances of recurring events, the iCalUId uses the [PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/29c1f7d9-004d-4256-9bfc-76a52c614955) which oddly enough doesn't calculate its value from the normal PidLidGlobalObjectId, so you'll want to modify that too.

```json
{
    "subject": "Subject",
    "start": ...,
    "end": ...,
    // the rest of your event request
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        // PidLidGlobalObjectId
        {
            "id": "Binary {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Id 0x003",
            "value": "" // base-64 encoded PidLidGlobalObjectId, it should start with BAAAA...
        },
        // PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId
        {
            "id": "Binary {6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305} Id 0x023",
            "value": "" // base-64 encoded PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId, it should start with BAAAA...
        }
    ]
}
```

Be sure to check out the [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocal/1d3aac05-a7b9-45cc-a213-47f0a0a2c5c1)
of the PidLidGlobalObjectId and PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId, otherwise you might get "Data is corrupt" or some other such errors when trying to create or update events.